# Adding Hyperlink To PHP Table

Tags: php, html, hyperlink

I am trying to add a hyperlink to a table that I generate via PHP. I used this syntax, however my page throws a 500 error. In my experience that means there is an issue with the PHP.

What should be altered in this syntax so that the hyperlink is properly generated?

```
echo '<tr><td>' $Row['UserID'] . 
'</td><td>' . $Row['First Name'] . 
'</td><td>' . $Row['Last Name'] . 
'</td><td><a href=Test.php?".row[userid].">".$row[Sale Amount]."</a>' 
. "$".round($Row['Sale Amount']) . '</td></tr>';
```

Comment: Capitalized PHP tag

Comment: you're missing a dot on line 1. It should be `echo '<tr><td>'.$Row['UserID'] . `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
echo '
<tr>
<td>'.$Row['UserID'] .'</td>
<td>' . $Row['First Name'] .'</td>
<td>' . $Row['Last Name'] .'</td>
<td><a href="Test.php?'.$Row['UserID'].'">'.$Row['Sale Amount'].'</a>' . "$".round($Row['Sale Amount']) . '</td>
</tr>';
```

Comment: That did not create a hyperlink.

Comment: @BellHopByDayAmetuerCoderByNigh I have edited the code. Do you get any other errors?

Comment: No error.  This does not produce a hyperlink, just merely writes the value of Sale Amount again.

Comment: The code above works fine. It will show the hyperlink with the Sale Amount being clickable - unless you want something else to be on the hyperlink text?. I have tested the code above on http://phptester.net/ @BellHopByDayAmetuerCoderByNigh

Comment: You are correct, I apologize.  When I was copying code to my production environment I missed the lead $ before Row and that was causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

1st line:

```
echo '<tr><td>' $Row['UserID'] .
```

Missing a dot here before $Row

4th line:

```
'</td><td><a href=Test.php?".row[userid].">".$row[Sale Amount]."</a>'
```

You start the string with ' but end it with ", use ' consequently

Try this:

```php
echo '<tr><td>' . $Row['UserID'] . 
'</td><td>' . $Row['First Name'] . 
'</td><td>' . $Row['Last Name'] . 
'</td><td><a href="Test.php?'.$Row['UserID'].'">'.$row[Sale Amount].'</a>' 
. "$".round($Row['Sale Amount']) . '</td></tr>';
```

Comment: This did not create a hyperlink.  It just wrote to the cell .row[userid] then the value of the cell.  I want the value of the cell to be a hyperlink.

Comment: When enclosed in ', variables within the string are NOT expanded, unlike ". I edited my answer, test this.

Comment: Produces a 500 error.  Maybe due to missing the double quote before Test.php?

Comment: No, the " is part of the string content. But i see another mistake here. Changing the answer.